# Eigenbasis of Hamiltonian and momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, linear-algebra

I was taught that, if two Hermitian operators commute, they share the same eigenbasis. Since the Hamiltonian and momentum operators commute, am I right in concluding that they share the same basis of eigenstates? Does this mean that the momentum operator, when expressed in matrix form with the Hamiltonian eigenstates as its basis, is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: The Hamiltonian of a system only commutes with the momentum operator for *very* specific systems, so in general your claim is not true.

Comment: Here is a QA that discuses when the Hamiltonian commutes with the momentum operator, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158855/commutation-of-hamiltonian-with-momentum